# Mapping data that were input to one module, to input to of module

Tags: java, oop, architecture

Lets say we have typical trivial CRUD app:

1. user sends data
2. controller catch the request and map it
3. controller sends data to service for processing

structure:

```
 - api
   - request
     - TestProjectRequest.java
   TestProjectController.java
 - service
    - testProject
       - TestProjectService.java
```

In code:

```
@RestController("testProject")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestProjectController {

    private final TestProjectService service;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public void createTestRequest(TestProjectRequest testRequest, HttpServletRequest request) {
        service.process(...);
    }
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class TestProjectRequest {
 ....
}
```

Now, the request that came to controller may or may not contain all neccessary informations for the service and we may need to enrich the data.

What is actually good practice for mapping data like this? In scenario where we wanted to enrich `TestProjectRequest`  for example of some data present in  `HttpServletRequest`  we can create another class for it:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class EnrichedTestProjectRequest {
 // data from TestProjectRequest
 // enriched data 
}
```

and in controller create mapper:

```
@RestController("testProject")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestProjectController {

    private final TestProjectService service;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public void createTestRequest(TestProjectRequest testRequest, HttpServletRequest request) {
        EnrichedTestProjectRequest enrichedRequest = enrichRequest(testRequest, request);
        service.process(enrichedRequest);
    }
}
```

Now we have `TestProjectService` as:

```
public interface TestProjectService {
  void process(EnrichedTestProjectRequest  request);
}
```

Since the `TestProjectService` method `process` now consumes `EnrichedTestProjectRequest`, the definition of `EnrichedTestProjectRequest` should be in in `service.testProject` package, as it expose API and we should follow lose coupling/high cohesion. However by following this logic, even if we did not enrich the request we should map the `TestProjectRequest` to some class that is exposed by module of `TestProjectService`. And this seems like it makes sense but also is a lot of work to follow some good practices.

What is the correct view on this? Does it make or make not sense to map data like this? Some good practices suggests every module should be stand alone, so if they expose some API, they should also expose the data structures that API consumes.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the loose coupling here, you can use the [Adapter](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/adapter) design pattern which suits very well on enriching/extracting data to make it compatible to a new interface.

Also, your `EnrichedTestProjectRequest` should extend `TestProjectRequest`, because those classes are linked, and in your interface you can have:

```java
public interface TestProjectService {
  void process(TestProjectRequest  request);
}
```

This way you make the contract more restrictive, requesting only the data you need and nothing more. This is just an example, you should update it according to your needs.

Comment: but using adapter does not keep loose coupling - since if i defined EnrichedTestProjectRequest in Service's package, the service package/module would be dependant on the API package.